# Syntax error for identifier 'iterator'

Tags: c++, dictionary, syntax, iterator, std

The following code throws two compiler errors in VS 2013:

1. The template function definition throws

   > error C2061: syntax error : identifier '`iterator`'
2. The specialization of that template function throws

   > error C2912: explicit specialization '`double getFillIn<double,double>(fillInOptions,double,std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,inputLoader *,va_list)`' is not a specialization of a function template

Can anyone please explain why? I'm fairly certain the second error is just a consequence of the first, but I don't understand why it can't figure out that `iterator` identifier.

```
#include <map>

template <typename T> class table {
};

template <typename S, typename T>
void f(S s, std::map<S, table<T>*>::iterator it);
```

Comment: Try `typename map<rngT, lookupTable<T>*>::iterator`.

Comment: I was wrong, but `template class lookupTable<double>;` before fully defining `lookupTable` will bite you. Off topic: the default cases in the switches return nothing. Good for a compiler warning and a bit of nastier debugging if an invalid or new  `opt` ever sneaks in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the compiler doesn't yet know the type of `std::map<S, table<T>*>`, it can't yet know that `std::map<S, table<T>*>::iterator` is a type (it could be a member).  You need to tell it that it will be a type, using the `typename` keyword:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
void f(S s, typename std::map<S, table<T>*>::iterator it);
//          ^^^^^^^^
```